# How can I dual boot Ubuntu beside Windows 10 on separate hard drives (Ubuntu in HDD and Windows 10 in SSD)

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I've downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.

I want to dual boot it with Windows 10 like this:

- Windows 10 in Solid-state drive 128 GB
- Ubuntu in Hard disk 1 TB

First I installed Windows 10, then I installed Ubuntu and installed GRUB on the hard disk.

All in UEFI mode and Legacy mode.

I disabled fast boot and... I've done all things!

But my laptop can't boot grub and Ubuntu. Windows 10 just boots every time.

I found these suggestions:

1. `sudo os-prober`
2. `sudo pluma/sudo pluma/etc/default/grub`

The first command found 2 OSes, but the second threw errors.

When I restarted my laptop nothing had changed.

How can I set up my dual-boot?

Comment: What you wrote about boot mode is not clear, but if your computer supports UEFI, you should install both OS's in UEFI mode.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Like wjandrea said, make sure you've installed both operating systems in UEFI mode.

Also, make sure that in your BIOS settings, the boot device is set to the 1 TB hard disk. What this will do is load grub, which will then let you choose Windows or Ubuntu each time you boot up.